# Facebook App multifiend request reject status

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Am building a facebook tab page app for my client. Here am using mutifriend selector for request friend to App.

```
function multifriend_request(checkedgame){
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        title:'Bayern3',
        message:"Mit BAYERN 3 und dem FC Bayern-Bus ins Stadion!"   
    }, callbackmultifriend_request);
    }
```

When i call this function a multifriend popup window opens and user can sent request to their friends.

Friends will get the request in their game centre like the following way 
[image]

There are two buttons accept and close, when they tap on accept it will redirect to my app and i will do some status updating based on that. But when they tap on close button am not getting any feedback. My requirement is to know the status of app reject status.

I have three statuses in my App page

1. Accept
2. Pending
3. Reject 
   Is there any way to get the Reject status for a particular app request. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not inform apps of rejected requests, but it does count them on the Insights page so you can monitor them there. The best way to handle this would be to timeout the request after x days.

You can call `DELETE {request_id}`, using your app access token, to remove the request after x days and log it as "rejected".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was searching for it all day, i didn't get any thread about it. What you mean by he "Insights page"?. 

Setting a specific time limit to delete request is a good idea, but i have already a status "Pending", when a user not acted on a request am taking its status as pending.

Comment: The Application Insights can be accessed from the Application Settings page. It shows you various stats about your application, like rejected requests and sharing.

Comment: Did u know, is there any way to get that blocked user details via api?